# How do I perform stepwise regression analyses with dplyr pipes?

Tags: r, dplyr, regression

In order to increase readability, I want to filter my data frame before I pipe it into a regression model. For some reason - however - this does not seem to be possible.

I can write something like:

```
model<-lm(mpg~.,data=mtcars)%>%¨
stepAIC(trace = FALSE)
```

....And that works perfectly, even with the pipe at the end. But then I try to replace the data argument with a placeholder:

```
model<-df%>%lm(mpg~.,data=.)%>%
stepAIC(trace = FALSE)
```

....And I get an error claiming that:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(data) : 
cannot coerce class ‘"lm"’ to a data.frame
```

This issue only seems to occur when I'm using the stepAIC-function. Unfortunatly that's a requirement for my current project.

Can I make this work and in that case how?

Answer (score 1):

the stepAIC part needs to see the dataframe from the environment, I tried passing it in many ways but it's problematic. One option is that you can try and still get the results is:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(MASS)

list(mtcars) %>% map(~stepAIC(lm(mpg~.,data=.),trace=FALSE))
[[1]]

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ wt + qsec + am, data = .)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           wt         qsec           am  
      9.618       -3.917        1.226        2.936
```

Another way is, if you want to run the same fit over multiple datasets is to do:

```
# example dataset with bootstraps
sampledata = lapply(1:3,function(i){
mtcars[sample(nrow(mtcars),replace=TRUE),]
})

# nest it in a tibble
tibble(names=paste0("data",1:3),data=sampledata)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  names data               
  <chr> <list>             
1 data1 <df[,11] [32 × 11]>
2 data2 <df[,11] [32 × 11]>
3 data3 <df[,11] [32 × 11]>

res = tibble(names=paste0("data",1:3),data=sampledata) %>% 
mutate(mdl=map(data,~stepAIC(lm(mpg~.,data=.x),trace=FALSE)))

res$mdl
[[1]]

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ disp + hp + drat + wt + qsec + am + gear, 
    data = .x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         disp           hp         drat           wt         qsec  
  -73.20988     -0.01714      0.03991      3.12230     -3.80928      4.08125  
         am         gear  
  -11.24742      7.17872  


[[2]]

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ disp + vs + am + carb, data = .x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)         disp           vs           am         carb  
   26.14918     -0.02344      2.11914      5.17128     -1.25915  


[[3]]

Call:
lm(formula = mpg ~ wt + qsec + am + gear + carb, data = .x)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           wt         qsec           am         gear         carb  
    -2.7017      -2.5837       1.4633       2.8117       1.8643      -0.8727
```

Comment: Okay, but can we delve a little bit deeper into the underlying principles?

For some reason, we convert the dataframe into a list with only one element. For other unknown reasons we use the map-function (a relative to lapply?) to the list, which applies our functions to the only member of our list. Finally, we make our regression model an argument of the stepAIC-function instead of just passing it via dplyr.

Comment: I'm not trying to be snarky or anything, I'm just describing the code according to my current understanding :)

Comment: No problem, as you can see the problematic part comes with passing the results from lm(mpg~.,data=.) to stepAIC. What you are doing with stepAIC is that you are trying to find the drop or add terms and evaluate the fit.

Comment: You provide a formula, so stepAIC will change the formula, re-evaluate the call by lm, and because lm does not store the actual data.frame, but only a model matrix, stepAIC has to try to find the data.frame from which all these started. This is why when you string them together it works

Comment: Ok I think there's one last part in your question, if you try df%>%lm(mpg~.,data=.) , this fails. Because dplyr %>% expects a data frame at every pipe, and the results of your lm does not allow that, so we use map from purrr to allow that flexibility to hold lists etc as results